# C# Compiler Error using typeof(Expression<Func<,>>)

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, typeof

Title basically says it all. I'm implementing some logic that analyzes expressions and uses reflection here and there. To retrieve an overload of a specific generic method that takes an `Expression<Func<T, S>>` as a parameter, I used the `typeof` operator to get the correct open generic type of this parameter:

```
typeof(Expression<Func<,>>)
```

To my understanding, using the `typeof` operator can be used to obtain open generic types. However, in this case, the compiler complains that it misses the type information from the `Func<,>` delegate:

```
Type expected
```

Is this by specification? And if so, how to obtain the correct type here? I'm using **Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 / C# 5**.

Comment: you need first get `typeof(Expression<>)`

Comment: in your case _open generic type_ is `Expression<>` and `Func<,>` but not `Expression<Func<,>>`

Comment: can you explain what you try do? possibly code-sample?

Comment: Duh, coffee must have got to me. `Expression<>` is enough :) Thanks for that reminder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [**`typeof`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx), you can get type information either about an open generic type, or about a closed type. You can't use `typeof` with a mixture of both.

`Expression<>` is an open type, but specifying a type argument of `Func<,>` attempts to reference a closed type, which is why the compiler wants you to specify type arguments of `Func<,>` as well.

Just use `typeof(Expression<>)`, this is the open type you need.